# How to redirect script output to the stdout of systemd?

Tags: service, console, stdout, daemon, systemd

Currently, I am doing some services migration from RedHat 6 to 7. In specific, from SysV to systemd. I meet problems of logs missing.

I have a service start script in RedHat 6, say scriptA. It will output some log info to console if I execute it to start a service.

Then with systemd, I use `systemctl start` to execute the scriptA, logs from scriptA can only be seen in journal.

How can I redirect scriptA's output to the stdout of command `systemctl start .service`?

Using `StandardOutput=` in unit file setting might be a valid solution, but I failed after trying all valid values.

Comment: I'm also looking for similar solution, have you found an answer?

Comment: @webminal.org unfortunately, not yet, I have to use a file to cache the output as a work around and read file anywhere wants it.

Comment: okay thanks the response @Gulli I posted questions under unix (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523912/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-custom-systemd-service-to-specific-console) - hopefully some systemd expert will help us. Lets see

Comment: If you try `StandardOutput=journal+console` in the Unit `[Service]` section and do `systemctl daemon-reload` and restart it you should see the output in the journal and the console device.

Comment: Thanks meuh. Hey @Gulili, checkout above unix url for the answer given by meuh. It worked me!